# hauppauge PCI cards /dev/video0 no longer showing up after hard disk replacement

Tags: ubuntu, pvr

I had a working MythTV DVR a couple years ago.  The hard disk failed, so it sat in the corner for a couple years.  Recently, I pulled it out, put a new hard disk in it, and installed the latest Mythubuntu (14.04 amd 64) on it.  However, the video cards no longer seems to show up in /dev anymore (used to be /dev/video0 and /dev/video1).

I can see the cards using lspci -v:

```
01:09.0 Multimedia video controller: Internext Compression Inc Device 0014 (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Hauppauge computer works Inc. Device 0001
    Flags: medium devsel
    Memory at 44000000 (32-bit, prefetchable) [disabled] [size=64M]
    Capabilities: [44] Power Management version 0

01:0e.0 Multimedia video controller: Internext Compression Inc Device 0014 (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Hauppauge computer works Inc. Device 0801
    Flags: medium devsel
    Memory at 48000000 (32-bit, prefetchable) [disabled] [size=64M]
    Capabilities: [44] Power Management version 0
```

I *think* one of the cards is a Hauupauge PVR 150 from comparing it to images I have googled.  I bought the DVR online from a small-time outfit that is since gone.  The cards are crammed in to an Asus Pundit barebone chassis, so I am not to keen on pulling the cards out unless I really have to.

I tried `modprobe`ing various modules, including `ivtv`. The only thing that shows up in `dmesg` output is:

```
[ 5934.162401] ivtv: Start initialization, version 1.4.3
[ 5934.162489] ivtv: End initialization
```

I am assuming this means that the drivers aren't recognizing the card?

I was wondering if anyone has any idea what I might need to do in order to get the system to get the system to create the device files.  Do I need new drivers?  Something else?

EDIT: I managed to pull the PCI cards out to get a good look at them.  They are labeled "WinTV-PVR-150 NTSC/NTSC-J 26552 LF Rev F0A3" and "WinTV-PVR-150 NTSC/N/tSC-J 26152 LF Rev F1B2".

EDIT: Here is the relevant `lspci -vn` output

```
01:09.0 0400: 4444:0014 (rev 01)
    Subsystem: 0070:8003
    Flags: medium devsel
    Memory at <unassigned> (32-bit, prefetchable) [disabled]
    Capabilities: [44] Power Management version 2

01:0e.0 0400: 4444:0014 (rev 01)
    Subsystem: 0070:8801
    Flags: medium devsel
    Memory at <unassigned> (32-bit, prefetchable) [disabled]
    Capabilities: [44] Power Management version 2
```

EDIT: On a hunch, I thought I would download an Ubuntu 8.04 live CD and boot into that, as that was the original OS.  When I did, the cards were recognized.  So I started copying all the `lspci`, `lsmod`, and `dmesg` output to a USB stick so I could compare to the new OS.  When I booted into the new OS (Mythubuntu 14.04), the cards were *still* recognized!  I am happy that they now work, but I am at a loss to explain why.  The new `lspci -vn` output is below (relevant section):

```
01:09.0 0400: 4444:0016 (rev 01)
        Subsystem: 0070:8003
        Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 64, IRQ 16
        Memory at ec000000 (32-bit, prefetchable) [size=64M]
        Capabilities: [44] Power Management version 2
        Kernel driver in use: ivtv

01:0e.0 0400: 4444:0016 (rev 01)
        Subsystem: 0070:8801
        Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 64, IRQ 17
        Memory at e8000000 (32-bit, prefetchable) [size=64M]
        Capabilities: [44] Power Management version 2
        Kernel driver in use: ivtv
```

EDIT: After reboot, the /dev/videoXXX devices are gone again.  I think it probably has something to do with the module load order, but I am not really sure.

EDIT: The fact that the /dev/videoXXX devices show up or not has nothing to do with the Live CD.  That is a red herring.  I have observed it *not* come up in the live CD and it has come up without the live CD.

Comment: What is the output of `lspci -vn`? (This will show the numeric identifiers, which would determine the appropriate driver...)

Comment: I edited my question with the `lspci -vn` output.

Comment: That's very odd: the PCI identifiers for IVTV boards are `4444:0803` and `4444:0016`, nothing in the kernel knows about `4444:0014`. I looked through the IVTV driver's history, and that has been the case since the very first version... I'm at a loss here I'm afraid.